# AWS Cognito IAM : InvalidSmsRoleTrustRelationshipException: Role does not have a trust relationship allowing Cognito to assume the role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a Cognito user Pool through a lambda function, using Go lang.

The IAM Role, IAM policy and the Trust relationship policy is getting created successfully.

But when I try to create the Cognito pool, I am getting an error,

`InvalidSmsRoleTrustRelationshipException: Role does not have a trust relationship allowing Cognito to assume the role.`

The trust relationship policy is

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Create user Pool API call is as below -

```
newUserPoolData := &cognitoidentityprovider.CreateUserPoolInput{
        PoolName:               aws.String(poolName),
        Policies:               &userPoolPolicyType,
        AutoVerifiedAttributes: autoVerifiedAttributes,
        UsernameAttributes:     userNameAttributes,
        SmsConfiguration:       &smsConfingType,
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

The service role policy should have the `service-role` path. For example the arn should be in the format `arn:aws:iam::{ACCOUNT_ID}:role/service-role/{role_name}`

The trust relationship should be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "{External ID}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the inline policy of the role should be

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:publish"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am still getting same error after I have inserted as above codes.

Comment: @akshay-shah Thank you very much. Your answer helped solve my problem.

Comment: What is the `{External ID}`? where to create or find it?

Comment: you can remove the whole condition part, it's only a sample for adding conditions.